# Uncertainty of interpolation when covariance matrix is given

Tags: error-analysis, covariance, data-analysis

Assume that there is a given covariance matrix of an evaluated quantity ( in my case it's a rection cross section $\sigma = f(E)$, where $\sigma$ is the cross section and $E$ is each energy point where it was calculated) $\mathbf{V_\sigma}$

This means that I have a file with the following data points (Energy:Cross Section:Uncertainty in the cross section)

> $E_1 $ $ \sigma_1$   $\delta\sigma_1$
>
> $E_2$    $\sigma_2$   $\delta\sigma_2$
>
> ...
>
> $E_m$    $\sigma_m$   $\delta\sigma_m$

and as I said the covariance matrix of $\sigma = f(E)$.

What I want to do is calculate the cross section $\sigma = f(E)$ at some energy points that are not in the file so I decided to do a linear interpolation between two evaluated points $(E_i, \sigma_i)$ and $(E_{i+1}, \sigma_{i+1})$. This means that the $\sigma$ at the desired energy $E$ will be

$\sigma = \dfrac{\sigma_i - \sigma_{i+1}}{E_i - E_{i+1}}(E-E_i)+\sigma_i$

This operation will be done total $n$-times, i.e. I would like to get the cross section at $n$ points by performing the interpolation at $n$ sets (each set consists of two data points).

The question is how to consruct the covariance matrix of the final $n$ points given the covariance matrix of the evaluated cross section?

Any idea would be more that welcome!

Comment: What is meant by $\delta\sigma_i$ (i=1,...,m)? Are these numbers or matrices ?

Comment: @FredericThomas : Thank you for your comment! These are numbers, i.e. data points!

Comment: From the yellow zone I would conclude that the covariant matrix of the cross section measurement data (here considered as the given random vector) is just diagonal with diagonal elements $\delta\sigma_i^2$. You are suggesting that there also non-diagonal elements, i.e. a non-zero correlation between the different cross section measurement values ?